# What's the difference between those "cache_as_ram.S" in coreboot?

Tags: x86, intel, osdev, cpu-cache, amd-processor

I want to learn how the "cache as ram" work, so i find some asm file in "/src/cpu/intel/car/" from coreboot. But there are four folders containing "cache_as_ram.S". What's the difference between them?

https://github.com/coreboot/coreboot/blob/428def4a6b7cae6b822270bc7231db81ca5ead05/src/cpu/intel/car/core2/cache_as_ram.S
https://github.com/coreboot/coreboot/blob/428def4a6b7cae6b822270bc7231db81ca5ead05/src/cpu/intel/car/non-evict/cache_as_ram.S
https://github.com/coreboot/coreboot/blob/428def4a6b7cae6b822270bc7231db81ca5ead05/src/cpu/intel/car/p3/cache_as_ram.S
https://github.com/coreboot/coreboot/blob/428def4a6b7cae6b822270bc7231db81ca5ead05/src/cpu/intel/car/p4-netburst/cache_as_ram.S

I find one of them will enable "no eviction" mode, but is there any other difference?

Comment: Are you talking about coreboot?  Like https://review.coreboot.org/plugins/gitiles/coreboot/+/refs/heads/main/src/cpu/intel/car/core2/cache_as_ram.S  That's what google found based on that filename and path.

Comment: yes,but there are four“cache_as_ram.S"in each folder,i want to know what the difference between them. Is ther any offical document?

Comment: Oh, I see "coreboot" is mentioned at the end of the title.  I didn't notice that originally, and the question doesn't link the code for anyone to look at easily.

Comment: Sorry, I have completed the description.

Comment: It seems pretty evident from the folder names that each is a variant for a specific architecture (plus the non-eviction mode). The Intel SDMs have a list of MSRs with their format. In some archs you also need to take care of the other threads/cores. It seems to me that it's just tedious legacy code and stuff like that. I guess someone could go on diffing the functions but it seems pretty boring to go into the details. I would just look at the core2 and non-eviction files and then archive the rest as legacy variants.